# ¿Existe algun permiso de archivos que me permita desarrollar mejor en mi devcontainer?

Tags: linux, docker, devcontainer

Actualmente utilizo [devcontainers en vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/containers) y claro me permite trabajar mejor todos los proyectos que tengo dockerizado pero cada vez que inicio un proyecto nuevo me toca crearlo directamente desde mi maquina local y no desde el contenedor y el proyecto por obvias razones quedan con los permisos de el usuario de mi maquina host ejemplo:

```
node ➜ /workspaces/Curriculums/client (master) $ ls -l
total 212
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root     60 Apr 29 14:41 app.vue
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root     93 Apr 29 14:41 nuxt.config.ts
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root    261 Apr 29 14:41 package.json
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root   4096 Apr 29 14:41 public
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root    615 Apr 29 14:41 README.md
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root     94 Apr 29 14:41 tsconfig.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 191930 Apr 29 14:41 yarn.lock
```

este directorio es un proyecto en nuxt creado desde la maquina host y al momento de entrar a mi devcontainer pues no tengo mucho acceso a este porque requiero de tener los permisos, yo para resolver el problema siempre he ejecutado el comando `chown NOMBRE_DEL_USUARIO:NOMBRE_DEL_GRUPO -R PATH_DEL_PROYECTO_EN_EL_DEVCONTAINER`
y esto me funciona bien pero claro si quiero modificar los archivos ahora no desde el devcontainer sino desde mi host no tengo permisos para hacerlo

¿Que permisos en linux seria ideal para poder tener acceso tanto en mi host como en el contenedor?